# SUM with Multiple Tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

The problem is the one who made the tables is not me. This problem base on database adaptation. So guys I need your help.

I have **Tables** that needs to be SUM the `Quantity` of the Items.

I use this **code** to get the Quantaties from `items` to `orderset_details` table.

```
SELECT
    I.ItemId, I.Code, I.Item, I.Minimum, I.Maximum,
    IFNULL
    (
        (
            SELECT SUM(ROUND(h.Quantity))
            FROM orderset_details AS H
            WHERE H.ItemId = I.ItemId
        )
        , 0
    ) as 'Balance'
FROM items AS I
GROUP BY I.ItemId
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

But there are tables that needs to be a **NEGATIVE Quantity**. My code only gets all Quantity for 1 item at time.

```
SELECT 
   sts.TransferDate as 'Transaction Date'
  , sts.TransNumber as 'Document Number'
  , orderset_details.Quantity as 'Quantity'
  , '' as 'Po Number'
  , '' as 'Sales Invoice'
  , orderset_details.Cost as 'Cost'
  , orderset_details.SerialNumber as 'Serial Number'
  , orderset_details.LotNumber as 'Lot Number'
  , location.Location as 'Location' 
FROM sts 
LEFT JOIN orderset_details ON sts.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = sts.LocationIdTo  
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION 
SELECT 
      drs.OrderDate 
    , drs.TransNumber 
    , orderset_details.Quantity 
    , drs.PONumber 
    , '' 
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber  
    , suppliers.Supplier  
FROM drs 
LEFT JOIN orderset_details ON drs.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.SupplierId = drs.SupplierId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION  
SELECT 
      stockadjustment.TransactionDate 
    , stockadjustment.TransactionId 
    , IF(reason.AddsToStock = '1', orderset_details.Quantity, 0 - orderset_details.Quantity)
    , '' 
    , '' 
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber
    , location.Location   
FROM stockadjustment
LEFT JOIN reason ON reason.ReasonId = stockadjustment.ReasonId
LEFT JOIN orderset_details ON stockadjustment.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN location ON location.LocationId = stockadjustment.LocationId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION  
SELECT 
      issueslip.OrderDate  
    , issueslip.TransNumber 
    , IF(issueslip.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId, 0 - orderset_details.Quantity, -1 * orderset_details.Quantity) 
    , '' 
    , '' 
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber 
    , customers.Customer     
FROM issueslip 
LEFT JOIN orderset_details ON issueslip.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerId = issueslip.CustomerId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '4786' 
UNION  
SELECT 
      invoice.OrderDate 
    , invoice.TransNumber 
    , IF(invoice.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId, 0 - orderset_details.Quantity, -1 * orderset_details.Quantity)
    , '' 
    , '' 
    , orderset_details.Cost 
    , orderset_details.SerialNumber 
    , orderset_details.LotNumber 
    , customers.Customer   
FROM invoice 
LEFT JOIN orderset_details ON invoice.OrdersetId = orderset_details.OrdersetId 
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId 
WHERE orderset_details.ItemId = '4786'
```

I only need from this Code is for the `Negative Quantity Condition` **LIKE**  `IF(reason.AddsToStock = '1', orderset_details.Quantity, 0 - orderset_details.Quantity)` and 2 other more query.

**HOW CAN I COMBINE THIS QUERY TO MY FIRST QUERY ABOVE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT    I.ItemId, I.Code, I.Item, I.Minimum, I.Maximum,
          COALESCE(SUM(ROUND(
              CASE SA.ReasonId WHEN R.ReasonId 
                  THEN  h.Quantity 
                  ELSE -h.Quantity 
              END)), 0) as 'Balance'
FROM       items AS I
CROSS JOIN reason AS R
LEFT JOIN  orderset_details AS H
       ON  H.ItemId = I.ItemId
LEFT JOIN  stockadjustment AS SA
       ON  SA.OrdersetId = H.OrdersetId 
WHERE      R.AddsToStock = '1'
GROUP BY  I.ItemId
```

Comment: Okay ill try it :)

Comment: The Query takes more than 300sec

Comment: Check that your database has primary keys for each of the involved tables and indexes on the foreign keys that are used in the query. Is that the case? Also, can you confirm that `OrdersetId` is a unique column in `stockadjustment`?

Comment: Sorry newb to MySQL i got an error 
          COALESCE(SUM(ROUND(
              CASE R.AddsToStock WHEN '1' 
                  THEN  h.Quantity 
                  ELSE -h.Quantity
              CASE Q.OrdersetId WHEN H.OrdersetId
                 THEN  h.Quantity
                  ELSE -h.Quantity
              CASE T.OrdersetId WHEN H.OrdersetId
                 THEN  h.Quantity
                  ELSE -h.Quantity
              END)), 0) as 'Balance'

Comment: OK, I will make a fiddle to make sure. In the meanwhile I made a change to the query (see `reason` table join and `case ... when`), which might help to improve performance, but the right indexes must be present like always with SQL to get some decent performance.

Comment: It seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf8e6/1. Are you really on MySql? Which version?

Comment: If it still does not work for you, then please edit your question, and add the create table statements, and some sample data for each of them. Because I cannot fix an error I don't have when running the query based on what I think your tables are like.

Comment: the record is over 46thousand

Comment: Maybe you can do like I wrote in my previous comment?